# MIPS assembly: print the Fibonacci sequence (with syscalls)

Tags: linux, assembly, mips, system-calls, fibonacci

Good afternoon! I have a **MIPS instruction program** that simulates the Fibonacci sequence. My program works by entering in a number `(n)` that will determine how many iterations the program will work through. The program spits out the correct results but i was wondering how i could output each sequence of number(s) of the `Fib` method. Heres my code first :

```
.data
msg1:.asciiz "Give a number: " # message for fib(n)
.text

main:

li $v0,4 #read string
la $a0,msg1 # set iterations to msg1 value
syscall 
li $v0,5 # read an int
syscall 
add $a0,$v0,$zero #move to $a0

jal fib #call fib

add $a0,$v0,$zero # add result into argument
li $v0,1 # output integer
syscall

li $v0,10
syscall

fib:
#a0=y
#if (y==0) return 0;
#if (y==1) return 1;
#return( fib(y-1)+fib(y-2) );

addi $sp,$sp,-12 #save in stack
sw $ra,0($sp) # save return adress to stack
sw $s0,4($sp)# save msg value
sw $s1,8($sp)# save fib(y-1)
add $s0,$a0,$zero # store msg value into s0
addi $t1,$zero,1 # comparable value

beq $s0,$zero,return0 # if s0 == 0 jump to return 0 block
beq $s0,$t1,return1# if s0 == t1 (1) jump to return 1 block
addi $a0,$s0,-1 # else decrement initial value by 1

jal fib
add $s1,$zero,$v0     #s1=fib(y-1)############################syscall needed#########################################
addi $a0,$s0,-2 # subtract two

jal fib               #v0=fib(n-2)
add $v0,$v0,$s1       #v0=fib(n-2)+$s1 ##########################syscall needed#################################

exitfib:

lw $ra,0($sp)       #read return adress from stack
lw $s0,4($sp)       # read msg value from stack
lw $s1,8($sp)       # read fib(y-1) from stack
addi $sp,$sp,12       #bring back stack pointer
jr $ra

return1:
 li $v0,10 # return 1 to result

 j exitfib
return0 :     li $v0,0 # return 0 to result


 j exitfib
```

Hopefully you saw, but i have two lines commented where i believe a `syscall` would be necessary to output each number per sequence (`$s1 = fib(y-1)`)(`$v0 = fib(n-2) - $s1`). I tried loading the correct code into the result register to output an `integer` but it still gives me problems (not displaying the process before the final result). How could i correctly implement a `syscall` so that i can print each number the `fib` method calculates before reaching a final result?

Comment: What operating system is the MIPS cpu running?  System calls are OS-specific.

Comment: Wow! Great point ! Didn't know that. I'm using linux. That's probably where my problem lies

Comment: Ok, I guessed it was probably Linux.  So presumably `printf` is the easiest way to format and print integers to stdout.  That's a library function, though.  The only system call of any use is `write(2)`.  Google should be able to find info on which registers the args and system call number should be stored in, before running a `syscall` instruction.  i.e. the Linux MIPS ABI.

Comment: Given _"The program spits out the correct results"_ and that the program uses syscall 1 to print the result, I'd say the OP is running this in a simulator like SPIM or MARS. So syscall 1 would be the correct way to print an integer.

Comment: It's not clear what the "process" here means, but those commented places are the places if the OP wants to see the intermediate results of the tree depth-first.

Comment: The process being the numbers you get before the final iteration of the Fibonacci sequence. Not just the final result